# How to install Samsung apps on non-Samsung devices and make them run?

Tags: applications, samsung

I really need Samsung Voice Recorder to work on my OnePlus 7 Pro, but it doesn't work. Samsung limits it to only Samsung devices.

I tried the APK but it doesn't work.

Anyway to run it on other non-Samsung devices?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung devices have not only just a GUI that is a little bit different but the changes Samsung makes go deeper. This goes down to the available libraries and APIs an app can use. They add proprietary features and libraries and if a Samsung specific app uses those features you simply can't install it on a non-Samsung phone unless you have heavily modified the ROM.

The app "Samsung Voice Recorder" is a Samsung specific app that only works on Samsung devices.

I have checked version [v21.1.06.11 as provided by ApkPure](https://apkpure.com/de/samsung-voice-recorder/com.sec.android.app.voicenote). This app defines in it's AndroidManifest.xml that it requires the following Samsung specific features:

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.samsung.android.feature.resopt" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="com.samsung.feature.device_category_phone"/>
<uses-feature android:name="com.samsung.android.api.version.2801"/>
<uses-feature android:name="com.samsung.feature.samsung_experience_mobile"/>
```

Only one of those features is optionally (require=false) but the other three are mandatory.

Note that features are device/ROM specific features, you can't just pretend that your device has those features.
Therefore to make this app work on non-Samsung phones you would have build a custom ROM that includes these features (usually special Java/DEX libraries plus the native libraries and potential device drivers, ...).